# Bootstrap Modal Bringing Up Slider when not necessary?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

http://puu.sh/4k57Z.png

When I open up a modal using bootstrap it unnecessarily brings up a slider bar on the side.

Is there anything in CSS that would be causing this?

How can I make it not do this?

CSS for the modal

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I open up a modal using bootstrap it unnecessarily brings up a
>   slider bar on the side. Is there anything in CSS that would be causing
>   this?

This: `overflow-y: scroll;`.

A value of `scroll` says to "show a scrollbar regardless of whether or not you need to do so".

> This value [that is, scroll] indicates that the content is clipped and that if the user
>   agent uses a scrolling mechanism that is visible on the screen (such
>   as a scroll bar or a panner), that mechanism should be displayed for a
>   box whether or not any of its content is clipped. This avoids any
>   problem with scrollbars appearing and disappearing in a dynamic
>   environment.

<sub>[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-overflow)</sub>

You can omit that property entirely and the preceding `overflow:auto` will cause a scrollbar if one is needed.

Comment: Yeah.. Could there be another reason?

Comment: Another style in the document? If you haven't already, use the browser tools to see what styles are being applied to the modal.

Comment: .modal fade, .modal-dialog, .modal-content, .modal-header